# How to test state store in apache kafka using spring cloud stream?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to implement test code for topology which I implemented spring cloud stream Kafka streams binder. I'm using functional style, so I want to test topology result in store. But when I called returns null from the store. Do you have any idea?

Here is my test codes;

```
@Log4j2
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
    properties = {"server.port=0"})
public class ApplicationTests {
    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafkaRule = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, 1,
            "input-topic");
    private static EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka = embeddedKafkaRule.getEmbeddedKafka();

    @Autowired
    private QueryService queryService;    

    @Test
    public void SimpleProcessorApplicationTest() {
        //I'm producing data here
            var result = queryService.getFromStore();
            assert (actualResultSet.equals(result));        
    }
}
```

It's configuration file for test project;

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: event1;event2;event3
      bindings:
        event1-in-0:
          destination: input-topic
          consumer:
            timestampExtractorBeanName: eventTimeExtractor
            dlqName: detail-dlq
        event2-in-0:
          destination: input-topic
          consumer:
            timestampExtractorBeanName: eventTimeExtractor
            dlqName: detail2-dlq
        event3-in-0:
          destination: input-topic
          consumer:
            timestampExtractorBeanName: eventTimeExtractor
            dlqName: detail3-dlq
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            state-store-retry:
              max-attempts: 2
              backoff-period: 1000
            replication-factor: 1
            brokers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
            configuration:
              commit.interval.ms: 10000
              state.dir: state-store-test
              application.server: 127.0.0.1:8080
              default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
            functions:
              event1:
                applicationId: aa-event4
              event2:
                applicationId: aa-event5
              event3:
                applicationId: aa-event6
            deserialization-exception-handler: sendtodlq
```

It's the QueryService class;

```
@Log4j2
@Service
public class QueryService {

    @Autowired
    InteractiveQueryService interactiveQueryService;

    public List<KeyValue<Integer, Result>> maxResults(){
        List<KeyValue<Integer, Result>> allResult =new ArrayList<>();
        final List<HostInfo> hostInfoList =
                interactiveQueryService.getAllHostsInfo("m1-store");
        for(HostInfo info: hostInfoList){
            if(info.equals(interactiveQueryService.getCurrentHostInfo())){
                log.info("Retrieving all key/value pairs from Local...");
                allResult.addAll(getAllValues());
            }
            else{
                log.info("Retrieving all key/value pairs from Remote...");
                allResult.addAll(getAllValuesFromRemote(info));
            }
        }
        return allResult;
    }

    private List<KeyValue<Integer, Result>> getAllValues() {
        List<KeyValue<Integer, Result>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Integer, Result> resultStore = interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(
                "m1-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
        resultStore.all().forEachRemaining(results::add);
        return results;
    }

    private List<KeyValue<Integer, Result>> getAllValuesFromRemote(HostInfo hostInfo){
        String targetHost = String.format("http://%s:%d/dept/local", hostInfo.host(), hostInfo.port());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<KeyValue<Integer, Result>> result = restTemplate.getForObject(targetHost,List.class);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should really populate the state store. How do you populate it? Using `EmbeddedKafka` is not any different from using a real cluster when it comes to testing. Did you try debugging your test and see if it is indeed getting populated?

Comment: Yes, I saw that populating it physically. Offset number is increase. Look at the comment in the test function. I commented out also I saw it when I debugged it.

Comment: Any chance you can share this project on GitHub so that we can run the test?

Comment: Thanks for your great support! I've shared on the GitHub temporary repository. Here is repo; https://github.com/kadiralan/kafka-test

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues I found. Your `application.server` property in the configuration was pointing to `localhost:8080`. Change that to `${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}`. Also, in your test, you are sending to the wrong topic name: `template.setDefaultTopic("stage.dashboard.iddaa.coupondetail");`.
You have the destination defined as `input-topic` in your configuration. After making those changes, I was able to get further, however, your `aggregate` call was not getting invoked at all. I didn't get a chance to debug into that, but I suspect, that has to do with your windowing logic. Basically, nothing was put into the store `agg-store` by your processor and that is the reason why the query into the store returns empty. Look into why that's the case. Hoping that these are some pointers for you to triage further.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm really appreciate for your support. I was replaced the topic name with the "input-topic" name. But, as far as we saw, I forgot to replace it with the input-topic. I'll do your advice and make an update. Thanks again!

Comment: No I couldn't fix it. I saw an internal exception. I think application server is not running when I calling it. Do you have any idea? Here is exception;
Cannot get state store agg-store because the stream thread is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED, not RUNNING